# Please, do all these sentences have the same meaning, or does the preposition used after spend affect the meaning?

Tags: prepositions

1. The US government spends billions of dollars to develop vaccines and drugs each year.
2. The US government spends billions of dollars on developing vaccines and drugs each year.
3. The US government spends billions of dollars developing vaccines and drugs each year.

Comment: As an aside, we don't normally add *please* to questions of fact or opinion, only when asking for a favor or an object.

Answer (score 1):

With the *Present* tense verb *(**spends**)*, there isn't really any difference in meaning between OP's 3 examples. But that's not true if we switch to *Past* tense (and discard "each year" to avoid connotations of continuity through Present and Future)...

> 1: *They spent billions of dollars to develop their own Covid vaccine.*
> 2: *They spent billions of dollars on developing their own Covid vaccine.*
> 3: *They spent billions of dollars developing their own Covid vaccine.*

...where #1 very strongly implies they *did in fact* develop their own vaccine, but there's no particular implication regarding success/failure with #2 and #3 (which imho are *always* 100% equivalent in meaning; it's entirely an optional stylistic choice<sup>1</sup> whether to include preposition ***on*** in such contexts).

To illustrate this distinction, I'll point out that #2 and #3 could quite reasonably be continued with...

> 2/3a: *... but all their efforts failed, and eventually they bought a vaccine developed by AstraZeneca.*

...but that continuation is unlikely with #1, which implies they *were* successful.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Whenever* there's a "stylistic choice" involved, it's likely that at least *some* people will assign different *meanings* to the choices made. In the cited context, *some* (certainly not *most*) people might say that #3 (without ***on***) is closer in meaning to #1 than to #2.